# Does SVG support "dragover" event?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I have some SVG-shapes (inside <svg> element) and when I drag one over another I need to highlight the latter one.

After some research I couldn't find mentions of native in-browser support of "dragover" events for SVG-elements (which is presented in HTML5 spec for html-elements), so the question is: how can I implement such behavior?

BTW I'm using Snap.svg 0.3.0 library and it provides dragstart, dragend and dragmove events but its "Element.onDragOver" is commented out in the source code.

Comment: Have you tried using something similar to the commented out code out of interest?

Comment: I think if the commented out code can't be used, I'm guessing it may depend if comparing bouncing boxes would be enough, or if you need some pixel/path check (which would be more resource intensive).

Comment: but yes [you can](http://jsfiddle.net/tbd3f0xc/) attach dragover event listener to SVG shape elements.